# Vault initialization issue with keystore on OpenJDK

Tags: java, wildfly

We are facing following issue when we switched from OracleJDK to OpenJDK:

> [Host Controller] 09:25:41,568 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service
>   thread 1-6) JBAS015899: WildFly 8.2.1.Final "Tweek" starting [Host
>   Controller] 09:25:42,674 ERROR
>   [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot
>   Thread) JBAS014612: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([ [Host
>   Controller]     ("host" => "master"), [Host Controller]
>   ("core-service" => "vault") [Host Controller] ]):
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: JBAS015804: Error initializing vault -- 
>   org.jboss.as.server.services.security.VaultReaderException:
>   JBAS013313: Vault Reader Exception: [Host Controller] at
>   org.jboss.as.server.services.security.VaultAddHandler.performRuntime(VaultAddHandler.java:82)
>   [wildfly-server-8.2.1.Final.jar:8.2.1.Final] [Host Controller] at
>   org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractAddStepHandler$1.execute(AbstractAddStepHandler.java:75)
>   [wildfly-controller-8.2.1.Final.jar:8.2.1.Final] [Host Controller] at
>   org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.executeStep(AbstractOperationContext.java:660)
>   [wildfly-controller-8.2.1.Final.jar:8.2.1.Final] [Host Controller] at
>   org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.doCompleteStep(AbstractOperationContext.java:501)
>   [wildfly-controller-8.2.1.Final.jar:8.2.1.Final] [Host Controller] at
>   org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.completeStepInternal(AbstractOperationContext.java:298)
>   [wildfly-controller-8.2.1.Final.jar:8.2.1.Final] [Host Controller] at
>   org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.executeOperation(AbstractOperationContext.java:293)
>   [wildfly-controller-8.2.1.Final.jar:8.2.1.Final] [Host Controller] at
>   org.jboss.as.controller.ModelControllerImpl.boot(ModelControllerImpl.java:324)
>   [wildfly-controller-8.2.1.Final.jar:8.2.1.Final] [Host Controller] at
>   org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractControllerService.boot(AbstractControllerService.java:297)
>   [wildfly-controller-8.2.1.Final.jar:8.2.1.Final] [Host Controller] at
>   org.jboss.as.host.controller.DomainModelControllerService.boot(DomainModelControllerService.java:441)
>   [wildfly-host-controller-8.2.1.Final.jar:8.2.1.Final] [Host
>   Controller] at
>   org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractControllerService$1.run(AbstractControllerService.java:259)
>   [wildfly-controller-8.2.1.Final.jar:8.2.1.Final] [Host Controller] at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [rt.jar:1.8.0_191] [Host
>   Controller] Caused by:
>   org.jboss.as.server.services.security.VaultReaderException:
>   JBAS013313: Vault Reader Exception: [Host Controller] at
>   org.jboss.as.security.vault.RuntimeVaultReader.createVault(RuntimeVaultReader.java:84)
>   [wildfly-security-8.2.1.Final.jar:8.2.1.Final] [Host Controller] at
>   org.jboss.as.server.services.security.VaultAddHandler.performRuntime(VaultAddHandler.java:80)
>   [wildfly-server-8.2.1.Final.jar:8.2.1.Final] [Host Controller] ... 10
>   more [Host Controller] Caused by:
>   org.jboss.security.vault.SecurityVaultException:
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: PBOX000140: Unable to get keystore
>   (/usr/jboss-8.2.0.Final/domain/vault/keystore.jceks) [Host Controller]
>   at
>   org.picketbox.plugins.vault.PicketBoxSecurityVault.init(PicketBoxSecurityVault.java:210)
>   [Host Controller] at
>   org.jboss.as.security.vault.RuntimeVaultReader.createVault(RuntimeVaultReader.java:82)
>   [wildfly-security-8.2.1.Final.jar:8.2.1.Final] [Host Controller] ...
>   11 more [Host Controller] Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   PBOX000140: Unable to get keystore
>   (/usr/jboss-8.2.0.Final/domain/vault/keystore.jceks) [Host Controller]
>   at
>   org.picketbox.plugins.vault.PicketBoxSecurityVault.getKeyStore(PicketBoxSecurityVault.java:688)
>   [Host Controller] at
>   org.picketbox.plugins.vault.PicketBoxSecurityVault.init(PicketBoxSecurityVault.java:205)
>   [Host Controller] ... 12 more [Host Controller] Caused by:
>   java.io.IOException: Invalid secret key format [Host Controller] at
>   com.sun.crypto.provider.JceKeyStore.engineLoad(JceKeyStore.java:856)
>   [sunjce_provider.jar:1.8.0_191] [Host Controller] at
>   java.security.KeyStore.load(KeyStore.java:1445) [rt.jar:1.8.0_191]
>   [Host Controller] at
>   org.picketbox.util.KeyStoreUtil.getKeyStore(KeyStoreUtil.java:201)
>   [Host Controller] at
>   org.picketbox.util.KeyStoreUtil.getKeyStore(KeyStoreUtil.java:151)
>   [Host Controller] at
>   org.picketbox.plugins.vault.PicketBoxSecurityVault.getKeyStore(PicketBoxSecurityVault.java:685)
>
> [Host Controller] ... 13 more [Host Controller] [Host Controller]
>   09:25:42,682 FATAL [org.jboss.as.host.controller] (Controller Boot
>   Thread) JBAS010933: Host Controller boot has failed in an
>   unrecoverable manner; exiting. See previous messages for details.

The same works fine in OracleJDK. Using the same keystore file that worked on OracleJDK. Both JDK version is 8.

```
jdk1.8.0_121
java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.191.b12-0.el7_5.x86_64
```

Anybody can point what's wrong with OpenJDK?

Comment: (1) Using blockquote for fixed-format (line-oriented) computer output makes it completely unreadable. Don't add >, instead use 'code' markdown by either adding 4 spaces or (much easier) using the {} button. (2) what version(s) of each type of JDK? (3) do the `keytool` programs for each JDK work on this keystore or what error(s) do they give?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vault (and Credential Stores) are based on JCEKS and there was change in JCEKS format in update 171.
Please add this dependency line `<module name="sun.jdk"/>` to `modules/system/layers/base/org/picketbox/main`

Or migrate to wildlfy 11 which already contains this dependency

Answer (score 0):

Issue fixed when the solution here applied: https://developer.jboss.org/thread/277727.